# How to fix: "Origin <localhost> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." -- with flask_cors

Tags: flask, cors, flask-cors

I have set up a server with flask CORS and had it working for sending data to a React web app that I built, but when I went to test the POST method it stoped working and now it is broken for sending and receiving. The error log in the console of the web app is: "Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Fetch API cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/ due to access control checks. "

I ran into this issue earlier and added flask_cors and it worked for a while. Here is my server code:

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/": {"origins": "http://localhost:port"}})
# Also fails with this variation
# cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
# Also fails with these variations
# @cross_origin(origin='http://127.0.0.1:5000/',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
# @cross_origin(origin='http://localhost:3000',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])  
def job_api():
    with app.app_context():
        job_data = get_job_data()
        json_data = jsonify(eqtls=[job.data for job in job_data])
        return json_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my client code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ job_data: data.eqtls })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable CORS policy on your API, so it can accept requests from across different hosts.

Just do a google Flask cors, and make sure you are Accepting '*' or specifically your URL.

If you accept cors though you should be able to accept all CORS and then make your API robust enough so that no nasty data can be requested

## Try:

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin()
def job_api():
    with app.app_context():
        job_data = get_job_data()
        json_data = jsonify(eqtls=[job.data for job in job_data])
        return json_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I read the documenttation, and can just add @cross_origin() as a simple decorator: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#route-specific-cors-via-decorator

Comment: I tried a couple modifications based on your comment (and just added what I tried to the original question) but it still fails the same way.

Comment: "cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/": {"origins": "http://localhost:port"}})" this line looks wrong... What is that r doing? and also Port should be your port, and it doesnt look like your using that cors variable..  Also @cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization... Content-Type has no space in it. Try adding * star instead of using localhost: @cross_origin(origin='*'

Comment: I'm not sure what the r is for but it is used in examples like: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. I've tried replacing both localhost references to '*' and it did not change the result.

Comment: Updated my answer based on the documentation you linked.

Comment: So I reverted my code to where it was previously, and your method works (and so does my previous version). This is very interesting though because what I am changing is where the data is coming from: if get_job_data() makes a call to Selenium in another file it works perfectly, otherwise if I have hard coded test values of the same type in the same file it fails...

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Your data-architecture problem, sounds like another problem.  Or just a couple of hours headbanging :) you will get there!